# How do you refresh recently created/modified arguments in UiPath Studio on UiPath Apps?

Tags: uipath, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-apps

I have created a workflow in UiPath studio that uses In/Out arguments. The data of these arguments will be received from a UiPath app and passed throughout the workflow process. After connecting my process to UiPath orchestrator I had access to all my arguments but realised I had made a mistake with my directions and needed to update my arguments. I made the updates in UiPath Studio and re-published my workflow to UiPath Orchestrator but the UiPath App is stilling reading the old arguments. I have checked that Orchestrator has my latest workflow uploaded and I can see my new arguments in that process, I just cannot find where to refresh those arguments in UiPath Apps.
Is there somewhere I can refresh?

Answer (score 0):

[image: UiPath Apps]

Open up the process under the Orchestrator tab in UiPath Apps and click the refresh button next to `Input, Output, Input/Output`. If you click on either word you can see what arguments are available now.

Comment: Can you add an image maybe?

Comment: The image can be found on the hyperlink named "UiPath Apps" in my original answer

Answer (score -2):

In UiPath Apps, you can refresh the arguments by following these steps:

Go to your UiPath Apps project where you're using the workflow.

In the project, locate the step or component where you're using the arguments.

Open the properties or configuration of that step or component.

Look for an option to refresh or update the arguments. This may vary depending on how you've set up the interaction between UiPath Apps and Orchestrator.

If you don't find a specific refresh option, try reconfiguring the arguments for that step or component to ensure they are linked to the correct ones in your updated workflow.

Save your changes, and this should reflect the updated arguments from your workflow in UiPath Apps.